# Seleccionar filas de una matriz en python dado que el número de filas a seleccionar es un valor variable

Tags: python

Tengo una matriz y deseo seleccionar cada columna. Después da cada matriz [nx1] seleccionada, deseo tomar un número de filas que varia de matriz columna a matriz columna seleccionada. Tengo en un vector columna guardada la información del número de filas a seleccionar de cada matriz[nx1] establecida.
Lo que llevo de código es muy pobre, pero lo publico:

```
import numpy as np
dtos=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[8,9,6,8], [11,1,12,9], [4,5,4,3]])
fil=np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
dto=np.zeros((4,4))
fila1=fil[0]
dtos1=dtos[:fila1,0]
print(dtos1)
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me indica que

```
dtos1=dtos[:fila1,0]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

He leído como seleccionar filas en relación al nombre de la columna, al valor de la celda ... pero no un caso como el que planteo.

Answer (score 2):

`"TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"` casi siempre aparece cuando estas queriendo utilizar un índice que no es compatible con el arreglo.

El problema parece provenir desde aquí:

```
fil=np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
```

Estas haciendo de `fil` un DOBLE arreglo:

1. Cada número lo estas envolviendo en un arreglo:
   `[1], [2], [3]...`
2. Todos estos arreglos los envuelves en otro arreglo de Numpy:
   `np.array([ [1], [2],[3].... ])`

Lo anterior ocasiona que cuando quieras obtener el primer dato de `fil`, obtengas un ARREGLO que contiene el primer dato, EN LUGAR DEL DATO.

```
fil[0] --> Se évalua como:   array([1])
fil[1] --> Se évalua como:   array([2])
etc.
```

Un arreglo puede usarse como índice de otro arreglo, por ejemplo:

```
fila1=fil[0]  // array([1])
dtos1=dtos[fila1]  
print(dtos1)   // [[8 9 6 8]]
```

Pero no puede usarse para recortar otro arreglo (lo que buscar hacer en `dtos[:fila1,0]`)

---

Yo veo 2 posibles soluciones, dependiendo lo que estes buscando hacer después:

1. Cambiar el arreglo `fil` a un arreglo de numeros, en lugar de arreglo de arreglos:

   `fil=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])`

   `.....`

   `print(dtos1)    // Imprime "[1]"`
2. Cambiar la asignación de `fila1` por lo siguiente:

   `fila1=fil[0][0]   // El primer valor del primer valor del arreglo`

   `....`

   `print(dtos1)  // Imprime "[1]"`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda ... La explicación me fue muy útil para aclarar conceptos y resolver mi duda.